# Using tags to denote 'unsupported' features?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a class of questions we get, which are perfectly valid - but the answer but boils down to:

**Blender can't do that**.

---

Often answers try to show workaround or some way to export to some external tool to perform the operation, use a hacky script... but they are often unsatisfactory solutions.

The thing about these questions is they can be seen as indirect feature requests, this isn't necessarily a bad thing. But since its a sore-point that the Blender community has an insatiable appetite for posting there wish-lists, I'm hesitant to promote anything which may make SE into a place to feature request.

Having said that, I was wondering if it would be useful to have an `unsupported` tag. This means...

> unsupported: The question is perfectly valid, but the functionality isn't supported.

---

As a developer this gives us the ability to view highly voted questions with the tag `unsupported`. Which can be translated into...

*Things which would be really nice to support and the community obviously wants.*

I'm wary to promote this though, since I think it could end up being mis-used.

On the other hand - questions can be a good way to highlight missing features too.

Some examples of features added as a reaction to questions, *(there are more, this is just some I could find from a quick look)*

- https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24101/55
- https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24102/55
- https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15692/55

The main downside of this AFAICS is.

- It can be seen as a mis-use of SE to vote up good features, not good questions.
- Users may knowing ask about non-existing features `"Does BLAH feature exist?"`, rather than explaining the problem in full, (which would be a better question). Perhaps these can be closed as feature-requests.

On the other hand, if a popular feature doesn't exist, assuming it *is* also a valid question being asked - newer users would probably ask at some point anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is best to leave tags to describe what the question is about, and *not* get into labeling questions with *other* issues by using tags. Certainly, you include that information as part of your *answer*, but using tags to describe things like like "not supported" or "too easy" (or *other* issues with the question) are what we call "meta tags", and they are strongly discouraged. See:

[**Death of Meta Tags**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Comment: Good point, for development purposes its nice to see a list of feature's not yet implemented, but I guess this could be maintained elsewhere.